# Do you have to re-archive your project after adding devices to the provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

Say you have an existing provisioning profile with some devices and you archive a target with that provisioning profile. Then, you go into Member Center and add some more devices to the profile. Do you have to re-download/re-archive the project in order for those devices to install the target app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if not - how can the previous profile know that you have added more devices to it ?

You have to delete the old profile in organizer and then you need to download freshly the same profile which is configured with new devices.

Note: don't forget to check the code signing in your project settings after installing the new profile.

```
                 (OR)
```

If you have already configured your iOS Developer Network profile in your system,

Just press the refresh button at the bottom right of your organizer

[image]

Comment: "Yes, if not - how can the previous profile knows that you have added more devices to it ?" - that is what I was thinking. I was wondering if maybe when they added it via iTunes it phoned home to the Apple server or something. Good to know

Answer (score 6):

No, as long as the name of the profile is the same, you can now distribute apps that include it to the new devices, as long as the new devices get the provisioning profile that includes their device ID.

Edit: A note of further explanation. Your archived app does not store the provisioning profile in its archive. You merely tell it what provisioning profile to look for in order to determine if it can run on a certain device. Therefore you can change your provisioning profiles all you want, and as long as it is the same profile the app is told to look for, you never have to recompile the app to recognize new devices.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I do it regularly -- post a binary with a distribution provisioning profile on my test server, then update the provisioning profile with new devices. No need to post a new binary. I just did it again today to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the new profile will have to be built into your app for it to work with the devices added.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download again the profile (or let XCode do the work for you).

You do not have to re-archive. Just share existing archive BUT sign-again with the new/updated profile.